# Entity Framework Core: SaveChanges() NON-async throws "A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed."

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am fairly new to Entity Framework and everything has been moving smoothly, until I encountered this error. My code is attempting to save children of a parent table using `SaveChanges()` but I get this error:

> A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.

This message seems tied to async calls and having to use await - `SaveChangesAsync()`. However I am **NOT** calling the async version of the `SaveChanges()` method but still get a thread error message.

My code is fairly simple:

```
public void CreateRange(IList<Section> sections)
{
    // Add new sections and save context.
    _SqlRunnerContext.sectionsDbSet.AddRange(sections);
    _SqlRunnerContext.SaveChanges(); // This line throws the error.
}
```

The error seems to occur when there are at least two entries in the list. Which makes me think it's the way that Entity Framework is handling the save internally.

The code that calls this method creates a new repository which in turn creates a new dao and `SqlContext`. Given this I wouldn't think it would be something outside of this code causing the issue. I have also tried a foreach loop and save each item individually with the same error.

If anyone could give me a suggestion or idea what to try, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks again,

Adam

Comment: I may have fixed my own issue by simply updating records that already exist and only creating new ones if they are actually new (deleting all before). I will do more testing tomorrow and write back.

Comment: Who instantiate  _SqlRunnerContext? When it disposed?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting all records then re-inserting. I change the code to simply update if it exists and add if new. This has resolved the issue.